# Python: search for a file in current directory and all it's parents

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Is there an inbuilt module to search for a file in the current directory, as well as all the super-directories?

Without the module, I'll have to list all the files in the current directory, search for the file in question, and recursively move up if the file isn't present. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I guess there is no module for searching file. Best thing to do is use `listdir` and `getcwd` and search in file in the list

Comment: I think you can use `os.walk` for iterating the directory and `pardir` to refer to the parent directory.

Comment: The `pathlib` module added in Python 3.4 is well-suited to this task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well this is not so well implemented, but will work

use `listdir` to get list of files/folders in current directory and then in the list search for you file.

If it exists loop breaks but if it doesn't it goes to parent directory using `os.path.dirname` and `listdir`.

if `cur_dir == '/'` the parent dir for `"/"` is returned as `"/"` so if `cur_dir == parent_dir` it breaks the loop

```
import os
import os.path

file_name = "test.txt" #file to be searched
cur_dir = os.getcwd() # Dir from where search starts can be replaced with any path

while True:
    file_list = os.listdir(cur_dir)
    parent_dir = os.path.dirname(cur_dir)
    if file_name in file_list:
        print "File Exists in: ", cur_dir
        break
    else:
        if cur_dir == parent_dir: #if dir is root dir
            print "File not found"
            break
        else:
            cur_dir = parent_dir
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `if cur_dir== '/' : break` ? or `os.sep` to be generic?

Comment: it is for all operating systems, if `cur_dir == '/'` the parent dir for `"/"` is returned as `"/"` so if `cur_dir == parent_dir` it breaks the loop

Comment: yeah, you are right. `os.path.dirname("/")` returns `/`

Comment: You should check whether reported file is really a file (or a symlink): `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(cur_dir, file_name))`. It also implies that file is on `file_list`, so you don't have to check it on the list.

Answer (score 6):

Another option, using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```python
from pathlib import Path


def search_upwards_for_file(filename):
    """Search in the current directory and all directories above it 
    for a file of a particular name.

    Arguments:
    ---------
    filename :: string, the filename to look for.

    Returns
    -------
    pathlib.Path, the location of the first file found or
    None, if none was found
    """
    d = Path.cwd()
    root = Path(d.root)

    while d != root:
        attempt = d / filename
        if attempt.exists():
            return attempt
        d = d.parent

    return None
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's another one, using pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path


def find_upwards(cwd: Path, filename: str) -> Path | None:
    if cwd == Path(cwd.root) or cwd == cwd.parent:
        return None
    
    fullpath = cwd / filename
    
    return fullpath if fullpath.exists() else find_upwards(cwd.parent, filename)


# usage example:    
find_upwards(Path.cwd(), "helloworld.txt")
```

(using some Python 3.10 typing syntax here, you can safely skip that if you are using an earlier version)

Answer (score 1):

The parent question was to walk *parent* directories (not descend into children like the `find` command):

```
# walk PARENT directories looking for `filename`:

f = 'filename'
d = os.getcwd()

while d != "/" and f not in os.listdir(d):
    d = os.path.abspath(d + "/../")

if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(d,f)):
    do_something(f)
```

Here's a version that uses shell globbing to match multiple files:

```
# walk PARENT directories looking for any *.csv files,
# stopping when a directory that contains any:

f = '*.csv'
d = os.getcwd()

while d != "/" and not glob.glob(os.path.join(d, f)):
    d = os.path.abspath(d + "/../")

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(d,f))

for filename in files:
    do_something(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a function that does an upward search:

```py
import sys, os, os.path
def up_dir(match,start=None):
    """
    Find a parent path producing a match on one of its entries.
    Without match an empty string is returned.

    :param match: a function returning a bool on a directory entry
    :param start: absolute path or None
    :return: directory with a match on one of its entries

    >>> up_dir(lambda x: False)
    ''

    """

    if start is None:
        start = os.getcwd()
    if any(match(x) for x in os.listdir(start)):
        return start
    parent = os.path.dirname(start)
    if start == parent:
        rootres = start.replace('\\','/').strip('/').replace(':','')
        if len(rootres)==1 and sys.platform=='win32':
            rootres = ''
        return rootres
    return up_dir(match,start=parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that will find all the .csv files in a specified directory "path" and all its root directories and print them:

```
    import os
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".csv"):
                path_file = os.path.join(root,file)
                print(path_file)
```

If you want to start at one directory and work your way through the parents then this would work for finding all the .csv files (for example):

```
import os
import glob
last_dir = ''
dir = r'c:\temp\starting_dir'

os.chdir(dir)
while last_dir != dir:
    dir = os.getcwd()
    print(glob.glob('*.csv'))
    os.chdir('..')
    last_dir = os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Thank you. I start from the current directory and move up a folder every time I don't find it. Since `os.walk` traverses the entire directory tree, I would have to provide '/' as the top, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question SilentMonk. For the "path" you can just give the root directory that you want to look in, for example: path =  r'c:\temp'

Comment: I would have to pass "/" since the file can be in any of the parent directory. If I pass "/" as the parent directory wouldn't that result in os.walk() searching all the directories in the file system?

Comment: Yes, if you start at the top directory then every file under it will be searched.

Comment: but I want the files present in current and all it's parent directories to be searched.

Comment: I see. It's not very pretty but a while loop would work. I've added it to my response above.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that I left off a line. I fixed it so it should work now.

Comment: @JamiesonBecker, did you read the second part of my answer? I think that answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this too, since `os.walk` is exactly the opposite of what I wanted. That searches subdirectories. I wanted to search backwards through parent directories until I hit the drive root.

Bumming some inspiration from previous answers, below is what I am using. It doesn't require changing the working directory and it has a place for you to do something when you find a match. And you can change how the match is found. I'm using regex but a basic string compare would work fine too.

```py
# Looking for a file with the string 'lowda' in it (like beltalowda or inyalowda)
import os
import re # only if you want to use regex

# Setup initial directories
starting_dir = 'C:\\Users\\AvasaralaC\\Documents\\Projects'
last_dir = ''
curr_dir = starting_dir
filename = ''

# Loop through parent directories until you hit the end or find a match
while last_dir != curr_dir:
    for item in os.listdir(curr_dir):
        if re.compile('.*lowda.*').search(item): # Here you can do your own comparison
            filename = (curr_dir + os.path.sep + item)
            break
    if filename:
        break
    last_dir = curr_dir
    curr_dir = os.path.abspath(curr_dir + os.path.sep + os.pardir)
```

Other comparisons you could do are `item.lower().endswith('.txt')` or some other string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

[The `Path.parents` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents) provides a pretty elegant way to perform this search that I haven't seen mentioned yet:

```
from pathlib import Path

def search_parents(filename: str) -> Path | None:
    cwd = Path.cwd()
    for search_path in (cwd, *cwd.parents):
        candidate_path = search_path / filename
        if candidate_path.is_file():
            return candidate_path

    return None
```

One advantage of this approach is that it also supports finding files in the root folder (i.e., `/` or `C:\`) without needing a special case.

Answer (score -1):

Just wrote this to find the "images" directory, note '/' is Linux style

```
dir = os.getcwd()
    while dir != '/' and not glob.glob( dir + '/images' ):
        dir = os.path.dirname(dir)
```